# Set up UI dashboard on single node Kubernetes cluster set up with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I set up Kubernetes on a Ubuntu 16.04 vServer following this tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

On this node I want to make [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) available but after starting the service via `kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml` I have no clue how to proceed. 
The UI is not accessible via `https://{master-ip}/ui`.

**How can I make the UI publicly accessible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to try running `kubectl proxy` on the client machine where you want to use the dashboard and then access the dashboard at `http://127.0.0.1:8001` with a browser on the same client machine. 
If you want to connect via master node ip as described in your answer you need to set up authentication first. See [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui) and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/).